# Session get another value when navigating thru pages PHP

Tags: php, html, session

My session is lost when I go to a specific menu on my webpage.
on login.php the session is created, then I am redirected to menus.php which is the main page for my user. If I go into usuarios.php and then select one of those users I am redirect to ver_usuarios.php and carry some variables on the url using get method.

When I get to ver_usuarios.php and if I refresh the page the session just expires it kickes me out of the webpage and I'm not using session_destroy(); never. You can see my webpage runnin here: http://santateclacentral.org/login.php user=alejo pass= 123 go to usuarios and then to each user and see the issue here is my code:

USUARIOS.PHP

```
<?php 
include("../conexion.php");
require_once('../sesion_usuarios.php');
include("../paginacion/paginator.class.php");
$query_usuarios = mysql_query("select usuarios.nick_usuario, roles.rol, miembros.imagen_miembro, usuarios.estado_usuario, usuarios.id_usuario, miembros.nombre_miembro from usuarios join roles on usuarios.id_rol = roles.id_rol join miembros on miembros.id_usuario = usuarios.id_usuario $pages->limit");

$hay = mysql_num_rows($query_usuarios);
if($hay){
    while ($datos = mysql_fetch_row($query_usuarios)) {
        # code...
        ?>

        <td class="resize"><a href="ver_usuarios.php?user=<?php echo $datos[2]?>&state=<?php echo $datos[3]?>&e=<?php echo $datos[4]?>"><img src="<?php echo $datos[2]?>" width="50px" height="50px"></a></td>
        <td class="resize"><?php echo $datos[5]?></td>
        <td class="resize"><?php echo $datos[0]?></td>
        <td><?php echo $datos[1]?></td>
        //Take a look at this , here is where i get the variables and redirect to ver_usaurios.php page 
        <td><a class="btn btn-info"  href="ver_usuarios.php?user=<?php echo $datos[2]?>&state=<?php echo $datos[3]?>&e=<?php echo $datos[4]?>">Ver</a></td>
        <?php 
        if ($datos[3] == true) {
            # code...
            ?>
                <td><a class="btn btn-success" href="activar_usuarios.php?user=<?php echo $datos[2]?>&state=<?php echo $datos[3]?>&k=<?php echo $datos[4]?>&activate=9468752130_edit" value="Ver">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Activar&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></td>
            <?php
        } else{ 
            ?>
                <td><a class="btn " href="desactivar_usuarios.php?user=<?php echo $datos[2]?>&state=<?php echo $datos[3]?>&k=<?php echo $datos[4]?>&deactivate=1679854320_edit">Desactivar</a></td>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <!-- <td><a class="btn btn-danger" onClick="borrar(<?php echo $datos[4]?>)">Borrar</a></td> -->
        <tr></tr>                                   
        <?php
    }
}else{
    ?>
    <tr>No hay registros</tr>
    <?php
}
?>

VER_USUARIOS.PHP?user=&e=

<?php 
require("../conexion.php");
session_start();
require_once('../sesion_usuarios.php');
$query_menus_usuarios = mysql_query("SELECT m.id_menu, m.menu_url, m.nombre_menu FROM menus m join menus_usuarios mu on m.id_menu = mu.id_menu join usuarios u on mu.id_usuario = u.id_usuario where u.id_usuario = '".$_SESSION['id_usuario']."' and mu.estado = 1");
while($menus_mostrar = mysql_fetch_row($query_menus_usuarios)){
    if($menus_mostrar[2] == "Usuarios"){
        ?>                        
            <li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $menus_mostrar[1]; ?>"><?php echo $menus_mostrar[2]; ?></a></li>                
        <?php                        
        } else {
        ?>                        
            <li ><a href="<?php echo $menus_mostrar[1]; ?>"><?php echo $menus_mostrar[2]; ?></a></li>                
        <?php
    }
}
?>                        
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="active" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Administrador<b class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<?php 
if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    # code...
    ?>
        <li><a href="menus/menus.php">Login</a></li>                                
    <?php
} else {
?>
    <li class=""><a href="../menus/menus.php">Administrar</a></li>                              
    <li><a href="../cerrar.php">Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: what do you mean? did you test the page i gave yo?

Comment: I meant i did what you said on your website, and session didn't get destroyed

Comment: @xNeyte It was destroyed for me. A key piece of the puzzle is to refresh.

Comment: @Alejo_Blue What does conexion.phpp do?

Comment: it connects to the database but that's ok. The problem is the session file that manage the session. i guess sesion_usuarios.php

Comment: @xNeyte did you go to usuarios menu and then chose an user ? there, on ver_usuarios.php if you refresh, session is expired or changed the id value for the user chosen. have you tried that?

Comment: these animated transitions are screaming "NEWBIE EXCITED DEVELOPER". you are making an admin system, not a javascript graphics demo. i couldn't navigate more than 2 pages, i started feeling dizzy. please, come back to planet earth. if you invested as much time for your code as you did on these transitions, you would have no session problem.

Comment: @Sharky you're right: i'm newbie, as a matter of fact, that is a bootstrap template i'm using.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you forgot to put `session_start()` at the top of the (each) admin page.

Comment: session_start(); is there. So this is not the solution. Thanks though-